# Deploy additional files in Gradle Application Plugin

Tags: java, gradle

I have a small Java/Gradle project.  I'm using the [Application plugin](http://gradle.org/1.0-milestone-1/docs/userguide/application_plugin.html) to create a zip distribution (using the distZip task).  Using the standard configuration I get the following directories in my zip file:

**/bin**  - The scripts to start the application go in here
**/lib**  - Contains my project code in a JAR file and all dependency JAR files.

The trouble is that I would like a third directory: **/conf** where I can put my configuration files (instead of having them packaged inside my application JAR file.

I imagine that this is a pretty common requirement because things like log4j.xml and hibernate.properties would be better placed outside the JAR file.  I just can't figure out how I can customise the behavior of the Application plugin to do this however.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I revisited this problem several months later and I finally have an elegant solution.  The following code should be added to the gradle file:

```
distZip {
    into(project.name) {
        from '.'
        include 'conf/*'
    }
}
```

This adds an additional include to the distZip task.  This copies the "conf" directory (including contents) into the Zip distribution.

The generated zip file contains a single directory which is the same as the project name.  This is why the "into" part is required.

Comment: Actually if you have a version tag in you gradle it should look like this.`version '1.0-SNAPSHOT' ` then the into() should be like this : `into(project.name+"-"+project.version)`

Comment: Should mention, that you can use info described here: [https://milinda.svbtle.com/copying-additional-files-with-gradle-application-plugin](https://milinda.svbtle.com/copying-additional-files-with-gradle-application-plugin). Also, I suppose that besides copying a file, you have to modify startup script to add this **conf** folder to classpath, if it is required.

Answer (score 29):

Actually, create a `dist` dir under the `src` dir in your project. Anything in this dir is copied by the application plugin (under `applicationDistribution`) when installApp or distZip is run.

Or edit `applicationDistribution` to do other things, if a simple copy is not enough.

Comment: this works with install, but distZip does not seem to pick it up on 1.9

Comment: I found this out by accident! Configuration by convention is great... when you know what the convention is ;-)

Comment: Works for distZip on 2.14.1

Answer (score 19):

For me, a simple

```
applicationDistribution.from("src/main/config/") {
    into "config"
}
```

did the job. Of course you need to have your properties loaded correctly from within code. Especially if you move them from src/main/resources where they have been usable via classpath,  into the new location. I circumvented this by adding a command line parameter which points to the configuration file.

Comment: You can have as many of these as you need, I have one for config and one for velocity to copy velocity templates.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure whether you can customize the application plugin, I have never used it. There is however other ways to achieve what you want to achieve.

You may create a `/conf` directory like this:

```
confDir = new File("$buildDir/conf")
```

You can then copy the files you need into this directory like this:

```
task copyConfFiles(type: Copy) {
   from _wherever your files reside_
   into confDir
   include('**/*.properties') // your configuration files 
}
```

You may then hook this copy task into the process like this:

```
distZip.dependsOn copyConfFiles
```

And last if you do not want your configurations in the final zip, you can do this:

```
distZip {
   exclude('**/*.properties') // your configuration files
}
```

Again, there might be a better way. This is *a* way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I've tried this out and I now have the "conf" directory (with config files) in my build directory.  Unfortunately I don't see a way to get this new directory included in the generated Zip file.  There doesn't seem to be a Zip file "staging" area that I can manipulate and there also doesn't seem to be any way to tell the distZip plugin to include additional directories.  Any ideas?

Comment: OK, it seems that you can in fact generate a "staging" area.  The "install" task generates a directory which contains all the files in the Zip.  I could generate this, then add my "conf" directory to it and then zip it up by hand.  I think that this will work, but it isn't elegant.

Comment: @JamesBlewitt I know it's been ages, but see my answer for a solution to running a separate task.

Answer (score 3):

OP's self-answer may be good for his use case, but there are a few things I'd like to improve on:

1. His answer suggests that he has a directory `conf` parallel to the `build.gradle`. There is no such thing in the Maven [Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). The general consensus is to have a `src/main/conf` as had been hinted to in the docs:

> If there are other contributing sources to the artifact build, they
>   would be under other subdirectories: for example src/main/antlr would
>   contain Antlr grammar definition files.

2. The target directory name is NOT `project.name` as had been pointed out in a comment.
3. If resource filtering is required, and it often is, then having a separate task is desirable. During local development, this task can be run to generate the filtered files. The distribution would merely use the output of this task (and unlike OP's answer, this also makes `conf` available to the tar distribution).

   ```
   def props = new Properties()
   file("src/main/filters/application.properties")
       .withInputStream { props.load(it) }

   import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

   task copyConf(type: Copy) {
       from("src/main/conf/")
       into("$buildDir/conf")
       filesMatching("**/*.y*ml") {
           filter(tokens: props, ReplaceTokens)
       }
   }
   distributions {
       main {
           contents {
               from(copyConf) {
                   into("conf")
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: This is the way. (the distrubitions.main.contents part) e.g. : 
distributions {
    main{
        contents{
            from('etc'){
                into 'bin/etc'
            }
            from('conf'){
                into 'bin/conf'
            }
        }
    }
}